# Does BuildShapes makes a database call?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am trying to generate custom markup for a bunch of queries. One query is filtered on the "Spotlight" content type, and has a shape layout that's pointing at Spotlight.cshtml.

Spotlight.cshtml

```
@{
    dynamic shapes = Model.BuildShapes;
}    
@foreach (dynamic shape in shapes())
{
    @Display(shape)
}
```

I'm using `BuildShapes` instead of `BuildDisplay`, because the latter makes a call to the database. Does `BuildShapes` also call the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at `ShapeLayout.cs`, BuildShapes is calling BuildDisplay, which is calling drivers to ask them for shapes. So if the drivers are making database calls, so is BuildShapes.

The more important question is what exactly are you trying to do? A lot of context is missing.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what else to tell you. I have a shape layout for a query. I'm trying to render it without making too many database calls. See the code here: https://github.com/bigfont/orchard-cms-modules-and-themes/blob/master/Orchard.Source.1.8.1/src/Orchard.Web/Themes/LccNetwork.Bootstrap/Views/ProjectionWidgetSpotlight.cshtml It functions just fine. My concern is performance.

Comment: Well, if you are displaying the results of a query, things to look for are select n+1 problems, which you often solve by preemptively querying related records in one go instead of item by item, or by adding joins (often by adding query hints from code). Your best tools to investigate such problems are the mini-profiler module, coupled with some solid analysis of the code generating the problematic sql queries. The Projection module also has some facilities in the form of the Eager Fetch filter that can help a lot.